# View not animating

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using this method to try to move my view up but without success, this is the code in my MainViewController implementation file :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
if (movedUp)
{
    NSLog(@"should move Up");
    rect.origin.y -= 50;
    rect.size.height += 300;
}
self.view.frame = rect ;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It is not erroring out and it's printing out "should move Up" so I know that the method is executed properly .

This is the IB hierarchy ( I`m trying to move the highlighted View) :

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I`m running out of ideas ..

---

Ok, Editing here I've isolated the problem to be something else, I'm using this code now :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];

self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and if I injecting this code in "- (void)viewDidLoad" it's working fine .

but if I use the same code in a different function in the same ViewController implementation file , it's not working :

```
- (void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp {


        NSLog(@"test movedUp");
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];

        self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);

        [UIView commitAnimations];



}
```

**BUT** it's still printing out "test moved up" so the code is executed, just the view not animating .

Comment: When are you calling this code? Animations will not work until the view has been loaded.

Comment: I'm calling this code as a method of the MainViewController, after a particular button as been pressed . Basically it's executed after the button as been pressed ( and the log behaves as such ) .

Answer (score 2):

go through this link [using the tableview as horizontal scroll and animating the views and also animating the text like marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932302/using-the-tableview-as-horizontal-scroll-and-animating-the-views-and-also-animat)
check in the method -(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender

Answer (score 1):

Try moving another view - not the main one.
Maybe there is a problem moving the main view.

If it works then add one more view to your views hierarchy that will contain all the others and connect it to a IBOutlet.

If it doesn't work then comment me and we'll try to figure it out...

Comment: ah, that's interesting . How would I explicitly specify an other view then ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can create add `IBOutlet UIView *containerView;` line in your view controller's .h file and connect it to some view in your views hierarchy (for example the one that is right under the main view).

Comment: Hey Michael, I did that : created a new containerView Outlet and linked it in IB, changed the code to self.containerViewframe instead of self.view.frame but unfortunately the view still doesn't move, ( no errors or warnings though ) .

Comment: Maybe this code is executed from non-main thread? Can you explain how and when this code is executed? Also try getting rid of the animation - just set the frame and see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, the funny thing is if I stick my animation code under "ViewDidLoad" it's working fine, as soon as I stick the same code under my own method (setViewMovedUp) it just prints the Log but does not move the view like it does with "ViewDidLoad"

Comment: I saw this comment to another answer. This is why I asked you about the thread. `viewDidLoad` is executed from the main thread and it has all the rights to manipulate view. There is a chance that your method is called from non-main thread and this is why you can't animate the views... Try to call the `setViewMovedUp` like this: `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setViewMovedUp) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]];` (instead of `[self setViewMovedUp];`)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[self.view setFrame:rect];
```

instead of

```
self.view.frame = rect ;
```

I think the animation will not be used for `self.view`.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it's still not moving up, still printing out the "should move up " message and not errors/warnings :(